# How to convert png image to inline svg

Tags: html, svg, png

How to convert png image to inline svg, by inline svg I mean the html tags paths, polygons, rects, circle etc
I dont want the svg file as I want to apply css to these elements.
Thanks

Comment: png files are raster images, and svg files are vector—there is no clean way to automatically convert raster to vector. You'll need to redraw the image in Adobe Illustrator or another vector graphic editing software, or hire a designer to do it for you.

Comment: But you can get svg paths by using some softwares or websites and apply css on them!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert a PNG image to SVG by uploading the PNG image to the website below;

**1)**https://convertio.co/png-svg/

But these websites will only give svg paths without any coloring. You have to use **fill** property of **CSS** to color the paths of SVG. To explain this I will discuss the following example with you;

[image: The PNG we are going to convert]

I used first website to get following save path and fill it with red color;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
path {
        fill:red;
      }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="200.000000pt" height="200.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 200.000000 200.000000"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <metadata>
    Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
    </metadata>
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,200.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
    fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M671 1970 c-92 -31 -193 -85 -271 -143 -66 -49 -190 -166 -190 -180
    0 -5 8 -3 17 4 15 11 14 9 -1 -9 -11 -12 -21 -20 -24 -17 -7 6 -32 -15 -32
    -27 0 -5 6 -6 13 -2 7 4 9 3 4 -2 -5 -5 -14 -9 -19 -9 -6 0 -13 -6 -16 -14 -3
    -9 0 -11 8 -6 9 5 11 4 6 -4 -4 -6 -11 -9 -16 -6 -12 8 -33 -33 -24 -47 4 -7
    3 -8 -4 -4 -14 8 -63 -86 -96 -186 -23 -69 -24 -86 -24 -313 0 -227 1 -244 24
    -313 30 -92 92 -215 104 -207 5 3 12 0 16 -6 5 -8 3 -9 -6 -4 -8 5 -11 3 -8
    -6 3 -8 10 -14 16 -14 5 0 14 -4 19 -9 5 -5 2 -6 -6 -1 -9 5 -12 3 -9 -6 3 -8
    10 -14 16 -14 5 0 14 -4 19 -9 5 -5 3 -6 -4 -2 -7 4 -13 3 -13 -2 0 -12 25
    -33 32 -27 3 3 13 -5 24 -17 15 -18 16 -20 2 -9 -10 7 -18 9 -18 4 0 -15 127
    -134 200 -187 79 -59 175 -108 272 -140 69 -23 86 -24 318 -24 273 0 308 6
    458 82 78 39 224 144 218 155 -3 4 13 25 36 47 22 21 38 33 34 27 -12 -21 4
    -15 25 9 23 29 24 45 2 27 -10 -7 -7 -1 6 14 27 30 41 37 20 9 -11 -14 -10
    -13 9 2 23 20 31 42 10 30 -8 -4 -10 -3 -5 2 5 5 14 9 19 9 6 0 13 6 16 14 3
    9 0 11 -9 6 -8 -5 -11 -4 -6 1 5 5 14 9 19 9 6 0 13 6 16 14 3 9 0 11 -8 6 -9
    -5 -11 -4 -6 4 4 6 11 9 16 6 12 -8 74 115 104 207 23 69 24 86 24 313 0 227
    -1 244 -24 313 -30 92 -92 215 -104 207 -5 -3 -12 0 -16 6 -5 8 -3 9 6 4 8 -5
    11 -3 8 6 -3 8 -10 14 -16 14 -5 0 -14 4 -19 9 -5 5 -2 6 6 1 9 -5 12 -3 9 6
    -3 8 -10 14 -16 14 -5 0 -14 4 -19 9 -5 5 -3 6 5 2 21 -12 13 10 -10 30 -22
    19 -23 19 -8 -1 11 -15 7 -14 -13 4 -28 25 -38 43 -12 21 8 -7 15 -8 15 -3 0
    19 -168 170 -242 218 -50 31 -30 9 26 -29 29 -20 62 -46 72 -58 11 -11 -12 3
    -51 32 -81 62 -219 130 -320 159 -38 11 -62 20 -52 20 27 1 159 -45 227 -79
    33 -17 60 -28 60 -25 0 9 -120 65 -192 89 -69 23 -86 24 -321 24 -243 0 -249
    -1 -326 -28z m798 -664 c55 -53 66 -107 66 -321 0 -268 -24 -336 -127 -356
    -55 -10 -707 -10 -772 0 -102 17 -131 94 -130 351 0 238 27 325 107 349 18 6
    202 9 429 8 l397 -2 30 -29z"/>
    <path d="M920 982 l0 -191 145 92 c79 51 144 94 145 97 0 3 -53 39 -117 80
    -64 41 -129 83 -145 93 l-28 19 0 -190z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
        </h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**output1:**https://jsfiddle.net/defenderkhan/0bsLdqfp/

If you are not getting some SVG paths from one website then you can use both websites to get different SVG paths and then you can color them as follow;

[image: PNG image we are going to convert]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .p1
{
    fill:white;
}
.p2
{
    fill: green;
}
.p3
{
    fill: black;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="200.000000pt" height="200.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 200.000000 200.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,200.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path class="p1" d="M0 1000 l0 -1000 1000 0 1000 0 0 1000 0 1000 -1000 0 -1000 0 0
-1000z m1245 841 c449 -132 709 -580 595 -1026 -66 -260 -249 -472 -495 -574
-208 -87 -467 -84 -670 8 l-67 30 -229 -73 c-211 -68 -229 -72 -224 -52 4 11
36 112 73 222 l66 202 -31 68 c-118 260 -119 510 -3 750 113 233 325 397 595
460 87 20 298 12 390 -15z m390 -184 c1 -7 6 -11 11 -10 6 1 11 -5 11 -13 0
-10 -9 -6 -28 12 -16 15 -26 31 -23 36 7 11 29 -7 29 -25z m-1195 18 c0 0 -17
-18 -39 -39 -29 -28 -41 -34 -46 -24 -5 7 -5 10 0 6 11 -10 37 11 29 23 -3 5
0 8 7 7 7 -2 14 3 15 10 1 6 2 14 3 15 1 3 31 5 31 2z m-100 -111 c0 -8 -19
-13 -24 -6 -3 5 1 9 9 9 8 0 15 -2 15 -3z m1427 -63 c0 -11 -5 -18 -9 -15 -4
3 -5 11 -1 19 7 21 12 19 10 -4z m-1620 -463 c-3 -8 -6 -5 -6 6 -1 11 2 17 5
13 3 -3 4 -12 1 -19z m1750 -80 c-3 -8 -6 -5 -6 6 -1 11 2 17 5 13 3 -3 4 -12
1 -19z m-148 -455 c-6 -7 -15 -10 -20 -7 -13 8 -3 21 15 21 12 0 13 -4 5 -14z
m-49 -37 c0 -2 -8 -10 -17 -17 -16 -13 -17 -12 -4 4 13 16 21 21 21 13z"/>
<path class="p2" d="M848 1715 c-231 -56 -423 -234 -504 -465 -35 -100 -44 -272 -20 -374
18 -76 55 -167 96 -234 l26 -43 -36 -107 c-21 -59 -40 -117 -44 -129 -7 -20
-1 -19 128 22 121 38 137 41 156 28 39 -27 163 -73 243 -89 158 -32 343 -1
487 83 36 21 101 74 145 118 137 136 204 301 205 501 0 270 -152 514 -395 634
-44 22 -109 46 -145 55 -81 18 -264 18 -342 0z m9 -405 c23 -52 42 -104 42
-114 1 -10 -15 -39 -36 -64 l-36 -44 19 -37 c44 -83 226 -231 285 -231 8 0 37
26 66 57 l51 58 107 -53 107 -53 -5 -46 c-8 -78 -66 -132 -162 -154 -47 -10
-64 -10 -122 6 -38 10 -108 39 -158 63 -75 38 -106 61 -186 141 -154 155 -214
260 -213 371 1 124 62 203 154 198 l45 -3 42 -95z"/>

<path class="p3" d="M877 1884 c-43 -8 -119 -29 -169 -48 -50 -19 -98 -32 -107 -29 -13 4
-13 3 -2 -5 11 -8 10 -12 -7 -21 -27 -14 -35 -14 -26 1 4 7 3 8 -5 4 -6 -4 -9
-11 -6 -16 3 -4 -6 -15 -20 -24 -34 -22 -45 -19 -16 4 44 38 9 20 -41 -20 -28
-22 -45 -40 -37 -40 7 0 -7 -20 -31 -45 -24 -24 -46 -42 -50 -40 -4 3 -16 -5
-26 -18 -16 -18 -16 -19 -1 -8 9 7 17 9 17 4 0 -16 -22 -32 -36 -26 -8 3 -14
0 -14 -7 0 -6 5 -8 10 -5 15 9 12 -11 -3 -24 -8 -6 -17 -8 -21 -4 -4 4 -4 1
-1 -8 3 -8 -2 -23 -10 -34 -16 -19 -16 -19 -9 5 7 29 2 26 -16 -9 -8 -15 -8
-21 -1 -17 16 10 15 7 -24 -77 -109 -236 -100 -512 25 -756 17 -33 17 -43 6
-80 -6 -23 -14 -39 -17 -36 -3 3 -5 -3 -5 -13 2 -31 -98 -322 -110 -322 -12 0
-38 -59 -30 -67 2 -2 9 10 15 28 6 18 13 30 16 27 3 -3 1 -17 -4 -32 -8 -18
-7 -26 0 -26 6 0 116 34 243 75 233 75 260 82 270 66 3 -4 40 -20 82 -35 276
-98 554 -65 791 96 45 30 58 35 47 16 -5 -9 -3 -9 9 1 9 7 15 17 12 21 -7 11
32 43 43 36 5 -3 16 2 23 12 13 15 12 16 -3 3 -23 -17 -24 2 -1 20 9 8 38 40
64 71 29 35 50 53 53 45 3 -7 3 -2 1 10 -3 12 -1 24 5 28 5 3 10 1 10 -6 0 -6
10 0 21 15 12 15 19 29 16 32 -3 3 -11 -4 -17 -16 -6 -12 -14 -20 -16 -17 -3
2 11 35 30 73 54 106 77 202 83 340 6 124 -10 245 -43 322 -10 25 -11 38 -4
47 8 10 7 15 -1 21 -8 4 -9 3 -5 -4 4 -7 3 -12 -1 -12 -11 0 -56 90 -49 97 2
3 12 -12 21 -32 10 -19 19 -34 22 -32 2 2 -6 23 -19 46 -13 25 -25 37 -29 30
-9 -16 -32 27 -23 44 4 6 4 9 -1 5 -4 -4 -14 -3 -22 3 -15 13 -18 33 -3 24 6
-3 10 -1 10 5 0 7 -6 10 -14 7 -7 -3 -19 0 -25 6 -15 15 -14 30 2 21 6 -4 1 5
-12 19 -13 15 -27 24 -31 22 -4 -2 -18 7 -30 20 -13 14 -20 25 -15 25 4 0 0 9
-9 19 -10 11 -23 17 -30 15 -7 -3 -19 2 -26 11 -7 8 -9 15 -5 15 4 0 2 7 -6
16 -15 18 -74 50 -65 35 10 -15 0 -14 -35 4 -16 9 -27 20 -24 25 3 5 0 12 -6
16 -8 4 -9 3 -5 -4 10 -16 11 -16 -81 17 -93 35 -234 61 -313 60 -30 0 -90 -7
-133 -15z m393 -49 c135 -44 237 -103 339 -199 101 -96 198 -260 235 -401 24
-87 31 -249 17 -340 -65 -398 -373 -681 -786 -720 -118 -11 -322 28 -435 85
l-35 17 -225 -73 c-123 -40 -226 -71 -228 -69 -3 2 28 103 67 223 l71 219 -31
69 c-65 146 -83 225 -83 379 0 150 11 212 61 330 88 209 280 392 489 466 117
41 173 49 319 45 119 -3 152 -7 225 -31z"/>
</g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

**output2:**https://jsfiddle.net/defenderkhan/t1279pv8/

**Note:** The color filling CSS code will become more difficult as you will convert more color full image.

Comment: You don't really need the xml declaration and `!DOCTYPE svg...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! if it still solves your problem consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the given website that allows you to make SVG path vectorization for the two different presets: high color and black and white.

https://theonlineconverter.com/convert-png-to-svg

[Here is the png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Vn3.png)

I will show you the example with high color preset for SVG path vectorization.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="512" height="512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" desc="Created with imagetracer.js version 1.2.6" ><path fill="rgb(80,171,241)" stroke="rgb(80,171,241)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 0 0 L 512 0 L 512 512 L 0 512 L 0 0 Z M 320 108 L 298 114 L 280 125 Q 269 134 262 146 L 254 164 L 252 173 L 252 181 L 251 182 L 252 198 L 253 199 L 253 203 L 252 202 L 243 202 L 216 197 L 193 190 L 171 181 L 141 164 L 121 149 L 108 136 L 106 136 L 97 125 L 95 123 L 88 135 L 83 155 L 83 167 L 87 185 Q 93 201 104 213 L 116 225 L 97 221 L 83 215 L 83 226 L 86 241 Q 90 255 99 266 Q 115 285 143 292 L 136 294 L 116 294 L 115 293 L 110 294 Q 115 309 124 320 Q 143 343 181 348 Q 163 363 139 372 L 114 379 L 98 380 L 97 381 L 79 381 L 78 380 L 69 381 Q 93 396 123 405 L 155 412 L 178 413 L 179 414 L 196 414 L 197 413 L 217 412 L 242 407 L 264 400 Q 303 385 332 359 Q 368 327 389 280 L 397 258 L 404 228 L 405 211 L 406 210 L 406 185 L 418 175 L 438 155 L 443 147 L 444 145 L 431 150 L 405 156 L 401 156 L 412 148 Q 427 136 434 116 L 434 113 L 416 122 L 388 132 L 385 132 Q 374 120 358 113 L 339 108 L 320 108 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 319.5 108 L 325 108.5 L 319.5 109 L 319.5 108 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 333.5 108 L 339 108.5 L 333.5 109 L 333.5 108 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 342.5 109 L 345 109.5 L 342.5 110 L 342.5 109 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 433.5 113 L 434 115.5 L 433 115.5 L 433.5 113 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 369.5 119 L 370.5 121 L 369.5 119 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 286.5 120 L 285.5 122 L 286.5 120 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 372.5 121 L 373.5 123 L 372.5 121 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 283.5 122 L 281.5 125 L 283.5 122 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 95.5 123 L 96.5 125 L 95.5 123 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 376.5 124 L 378.5 127 L 376.5 124 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 279.5 125 L 269.5 136 L 279.5 125 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 428.5 127 L 427.5 129 L 428.5 127 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 100.5 129 L 105.5 135 L 100.5 129 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 426.5 130 L 425.5 132 L 426.5 130 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 424.5 133 L 422.5 136 L 424.5 133 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 107.5 136 L 117.5 147 L 107.5 136 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 267.5 138 L 266.5 140 L 267.5 138 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 419.5 139 L 411.5 148 L 419.5 139 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 84.5 147 L 85 149.5 L 84 149.5 L 84.5 147 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 121.5 149 L 122.5 151 L 121.5 149 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 408.5 149 L 405.5 153 L 408.5 149 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 440.5 150 L 439.5 152 L 440.5 150 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 126.5 153 L 128.5 156 L 126.5 153 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 403.5 153 L 402.5 155 L 403.5 153 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 83.5 154 L 84 166.5 L 83 166.5 L 83.5 154 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 437.5 154 L 432.5 160 L 437.5 154 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 405.5 155 L 408 155.5 L 405.5 156 L 405.5 155 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 131.5 157 L 132.5 159 L 131.5 157 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 134.5 159 L 135.5 161 L 134.5 159 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 137.5 161 L 138.5 163 L 137.5 161 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 422.5 169 L 417.5 175 L 422.5 169 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 151.5 170 L 152.5 172 L 151.5 170 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 84.5 171 L 85 173.5 L 84 173.5 L 84.5 171 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 252.5 172 L 253 174.5 L 252 174.5 L 252.5 172 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 156.5 173 L 157.5 175 L 156.5 173 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 85.5 176 L 86 178.5 L 85 178.5 L 85.5 176 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 413.5 177 L 410.5 181 L 413.5 177 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 251.5 181 L 252 188.5 L 251 188.5 L 251.5 181 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 407.5 182 L 406.5 184 L 407.5 182 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 252.5 195 L 253 197.5 L 252 197.5 L 252.5 195 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 227.5 199 L 230 199.5 L 227.5 200 L 227.5 199 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 95.5 200 L 96.5 202 L 95.5 200 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 232.5 200 L 235 200.5 L 232.5 201 L 232.5 200 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 405.5 200 L 406 209.5 L 405 209.5 L 405.5 200 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 239.5 201 L 242 201.5 L 239.5 202 L 239.5 201 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 246.5 202 L 252 202.5 L 246.5 203 L 246.5 202 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 97.5 203 L 98.5 205 L 97.5 203 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 100.5 207 L 102.5 210 L 100.5 207 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 104.5 212 L 116.5 225 L 104.5 212 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 83 215 L 85 215.5 L 84 216.5 L 83.5 226 L 83 215 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 404.5 216 L 405 219.5 L 404 219.5 L 404.5 216 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 105.5 223 L 108 223.5 L 105.5 224 L 105.5 223 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 111.5 224 L 114 224.5 L 111.5 225 L 111.5 224 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 403.5 224 L 404 227.5 L 403 227.5 L 403.5 224 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 84.5 229 L 85 231.5 L 84 231.5 L 84.5 229 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 402.5 230 L 403 232.5 L 402 232.5 L 402.5 230 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 401.5 236 L 402 238.5 L 401 238.5 L 401.5 236 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 94.5 258 L 95.5 260 L 94.5 258 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 96.5 261 L 97.5 263 L 96.5 261 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 99.5 265 L 108.5 275 L 99.5 265 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 111.5 276 L 112.5 278 L 111.5 276 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 117.5 280 L 118.5 282 L 117.5 280 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 143.5 291 L 142.5 293 L 141 292.5 L 143.5 291 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 110.5 293 L 115 293.5 L 110.5 294 L 110.5 293 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 120.5 294 L 128 294.5 L 120.5 295 L 120.5 294 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 381.5 294 L 381 295.5 L 379.5 298 L 380 296.5 L 381.5 294 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 376.5 303 L 375.5 305 L 376.5 303 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 373.5 308 L 372.5 310 L 373.5 308 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 117.5 309 L 118.5 311 L 117.5 309 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 119.5 312 L 120.5 314 L 119.5 312 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 124.5 319 L 133.5 329 L 124.5 319 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 365.5 320 L 364.5 322 L 365.5 320 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 363.5 323 L 362.5 325 L 363.5 323 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 360.5 327 L 358.5 330 L 360.5 327 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 136.5 330 L 138.5 333 L 136.5 330 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 356.5 332 L 353.5 336 L 356.5 332 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 350.5 339 L 343.5 347 L 350.5 339 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 169.5 345 L 172 345.5 L 169.5 346 L 169.5 345 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 176.5 346 L 180 346.5 L 176.5 347 L 176.5 346 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 179.5 348 L 177.5 351 L 179.5 348 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 339.5 350 L 331.5 359 L 339.5 350 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 175.5 351 L 173.5 354 L 175.5 351 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 171.5 354 L 170.5 356 L 171.5 354 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 168.5 356 L 167.5 358 L 168.5 356 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 327.5 361 L 325.5 364 L 327.5 361 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 322.5 365 L 320.5 368 L 322.5 365 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 317.5 369 L 316.5 371 L 317.5 369 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 313.5 372 L 312.5 374 L 313.5 372 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 310.5 374 L 309.5 376 L 310.5 374 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 307.5 376 L 306.5 378 L 307.5 376 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 118.5 377 L 121 377.5 L 118.5 378 L 118.5 377 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 304.5 378 L 303.5 380 L 304.5 378 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 107.5 379 L 111 379.5 L 107.5 380 L 107.5 379 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 73.5 380 L 78 380.5 L 73.5 381 L 73.5 380 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 97.5 380 L 104 380.5 L 97.5 381 L 97.5 380 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 73.5 382 L 74.5 384 L 73.5 382 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 294.5 384 L 293.5 386 L 294.5 384 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 78.5 385 L 79.5 387 L 78.5 385 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 231.5 408 L 234 408.5 L 231.5 409 L 231.5 408 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 143.5 409 L 146 409.5 L 143.5 410 L 143.5 409 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 226.5 409 L 229 409.5 L 226.5 410 L 226.5 409 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 148.5 410 L 151 410.5 L 148.5 411 L 148.5 410 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 154.5 411 L 159 411.5 L 154.5 412 L 154.5 411 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 213.5 411 L 217 411.5 L 213.5 412 L 213.5 411 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 163.5 412 L 168 412.5 L 163.5 413 L 163.5 412 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 203.5 412 L 209 412.5 L 203.5 413 L 203.5 412 Z " /><path fill="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke="rgb(217,236,251)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 178.5 413 L 196 413.5 L 178.5 414 L 178.5 413 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 330.5 108 L 333 108.5 L 330.5 109 L 330.5 108 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 374.5 123 L 375.5 125 L 374.5 123 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 97.5 126 L 99.5 129 L 97.5 126 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 379.5 127 L 384.5 133 L 379.5 127 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 421.5 136 L 420.5 138 L 421.5 136 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 118.5 147 L 119.5 149 L 118.5 147 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 410.5 147 L 409.5 149 L 410.5 147 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 123.5 151 L 124.5 153 L 123.5 151 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 400.5 155 L 401.5 157 Q 398.7 157.7 400.5 155 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 431.5 160 L 423.5 169 L 431.5 160 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 416.5 174 L 414.5 177 L 416.5 174 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 409.5 180 L 408.5 182 L 409.5 180 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 405.5 184 L 406 189.5 L 405 189.5 L 405.5 184 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 405.5 196 L 406 199.5 L 405 199.5 L 405.5 196 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 103.5 210 L 104.5 212 L 103.5 210 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 98.5 263 L 99.5 265 L 98.5 263 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 109.5 274 L 110.5 276 L 109.5 274 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 144.5 291 L 143.5 293 L 144.5 291 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 117.5 294 L 120 294.5 L 117.5 295 L 117.5 294 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 123.5 317 L 124.5 319 L 123.5 317 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 366.5 318 L 365.5 320 L 366.5 318 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 361.5 325 L 360.5 327 L 361.5 325 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 134.5 328 L 135.5 330 L 134.5 328 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 357.5 330 L 356.5 332 L 357.5 330 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 352.5 336 L 350.5 339 L 352.5 336 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 180.5 346 Q 183.5 347.5 180.5 349 L 180.5 346 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 342.5 347 L 340.5 350 L 342.5 347 Z " /><path fill="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke="rgb(254,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 330.5 358 L 328.5 361 L 330.5 358 Z " /><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 327.5 108 L 345.5 110 L 360.5 115 Q 374.8 121.7 384.5 133 L 386.5 133 Q 411.7 125.4 433 115 L 427 129.5 L 411.5 147 L 400 155 Q 398.9 157.7 401.5 157 L 429.5 151 L 441.5 146 L 442 147.5 L 438 153.5 L 417.5 174 L 405 184.5 L 406 195.5 L 405 196.5 L 404 222.5 L 401 239.5 Q 395.8 262.8 387 282.5 Q 366.3 327.3 331.5 358 Q 302 384.5 261.5 400 L 242.5 406 L 219.5 411 L 202.5 412 L 201.5 413 L 169.5 413 L 168.5 412 L 152.5 411 L 125.5 405 Q 94.7 396.3 71 380.5 L 72.5 381 L 104.5 381 L 128.5 376 Q 159.9 366.4 182 347.5 L 180.5 346 L 168.5 345 L 152.5 340 Q 135.9 332.6 125 319.5 Q 116.2 308.8 111 294.5 L 116.5 294 L 117.5 295 L 129.5 295 L 130.5 294 L 143.5 293 L 145 291.5 Q 128.8 287.7 116.5 280 L 100 265.5 Q 90.5 254.5 86 238.5 L 84 227.5 L 84 216.5 L 85.5 217 L 104.5 224 L 116.5 225 L 105 212.5 Q 94.5 201 88 185.5 L 84 169.5 L 84 151.5 Q 86.8 135.3 94.5 124 L 97 125.5 L 106 137 L 133.5 160 Q 152.6 173.9 175.5 184 Q 194.9 192.6 217.5 198 L 245.5 203 L 254 203 L 252 193.5 L 252 176.5 Q 257.6 143.1 279.5 126 Q 290.2 117.2 304.5 112 L 327.5 108 Z " /></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On many of the websites I have worked on that involve a CMS, the file manager does not handle SVGs very well. If I want to be able to store SVG icons or elements in the file manager, it is treated as an image and typically outputted using img tags, restricting any styling I'd like to add such as fill and stroke colors or animations. So, I created a function in JavaScript that would be able to run through the page for me and convert those img tags to inline svg:

more : [supportingainain](https://supportingainain.com/)

```js
const convertImages = (query, callback) => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(query);

  images.forEach(image => {
    fetch(image.src)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const svg = parser.parseFromString(data, 'image/svg+xml').querySelector('svg');

        if (image.id) svg.id = image.id;
        if (image.className) svg.classList = image.classList;

        image.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, image);
      })
      .then(callback)
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  });
}
```

It's a pretty simple function that takes a query and a callback as arguments. All you need to do is call that function with a query for the images you want to convert, and it will loop through each of them, fetch the SVG and use DOMParser to pull the SVG data from the file. After that, it copies the id and class attributes from the image to the SVG variable and replaces the image with the SVG data.

**NOTE :** *You can see it in action here, you'll notice that the html just has an image tag but if you inspect the page, it has been replaced with inline SVG. Now you can do whatever you want with the graphic!*

Feel free to edit this to your needs, it's possible to copy over more than just the id and class attributes, and it would probably be good to do a test and check elements to make sure they are img tags before fetching data.